# Drupal 7 - How to use preprocess functions the right way?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

within my **page.tpl.php** I have the following code which makes some trouble in the backend. Therefore I want to solve it the better way, with preprocess functions.

```
if (!path_is_admin(current_path())) {
                    $pathArray = explode('/', current_path());
                    if (!empty($pathArray)) {
                        $path_to_node = url("node/".$pathArray[1]);
                        $img = '<img src="'.$theme_path.'/images/default.png" alt="Default" />';                        
                        if (!empty($path_to_node)) {
                            $menuChildArray = explode('/', $path_to_node);
                            if (!empty($menuChildArray[2])) {
                                $menuParent = $menuChildArray[2];
                                    switch($menuParent) {
                                        case "one":
                                        $img = '<img src="'.$theme_path.'/images/one.png" alt="Pic tne!" />';
                                        break;

                                        case "two":
                                        default:
                                        $img = '<img src="'.$theme_path.'/images/two.png" alt="Pic two!" />';
                                        break;
                                    }

                            }
                        print $img;                         
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But how can I realize this? To try it, I did the following:

I added a **template.php** to the Theme folder and added:

```
function set2015_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $variables['set2015_pics'] = 'test';
}
```

Within page.tpl.php I then did:

```
<?php
    print $set2015_pics;
```

But nothing is getting printed... What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that set2015 is the name of your theme everything looks good so clearing cache with drush or at config/development/performance should make the variable show up. If set2015 is not the name of your theme then rename the function set2015_preprocess_page to YOURTHEME_preprocess_page

Answer (score 0):

Debug it. Add some `echo "I'm here";` above first `if`, then bellow it, then after second `if` and so on...to see what is executed and what's not. Try localizing the problem.